# Android webview height doesn't fill in the screen size

Tags: android, xml, webview

I am developing an android app for a videogame website and I need to make a tabbed layout. In each tab there must be a webview because I have to load on it some apposite `php` pages I have created.

[onCreate code here](http://pastebin.com/4dMYxfTV)

The first tab has a webview formatted in this way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.leaderboardmk8.MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK7sd.png). The 2nd tab has this XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.leaderboardmk8.MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason this `webview2` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QTI0.png): as you can see there's only a small part of the WebView component on the top. I don't know where is the problem because I typed:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: i think you are using three `webview` and all are in same layout with `match_parent`?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the same layout for both tabs?